# Trigger not created in Mysql

Tags: mysql, privileges

I have created one user in cpanel and DB and gave `ALLPRIVILEGES` to that user and tried to import sql dump which results "`TRIGGER command denied to user 'test'@'localhost' for table 'tablename'`" .But it works in my local.What i done wrong on this process? .kindly help me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Error says that user 'test'@'localhost' misses TRIGGER privilege. Check granted privileges with 'SHOW GRANTS' command, it will show privileges for current user.

To grant this privilege at global level execute this statement -

```
GRANT Trigger ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost'
```

or at object level (for specified table) -

```
GRANT Trigger ON TABLE database_name.tablename TO 'test'@'localhost'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it work now ....i gave wrong db name when creating trigger....